# C++ template parameter inference

Tags: c++, templates

As an exercise I am trying to write an array implementation using templates, but with a function pointer as a template parameter. This function would be called every time the array gets indexed.

```
template<typename T, int size>
using Array_fnIndex = void (*)(int index);

template<typename T, int size, typename Array_fnIndex<T, size> fnIndex>
struct Array {
    T data[size];
    T& operator[](int index) {
        fnIndex(index);
        return data[index];
    }
};

// example index function
template<typename T, int size>
void checkIndex(int index) {
    assert(index < size);
}

int main() {
    Array<int, 10, checkIndex<int, 10>> a; // this works
    Array<int, 10, checkIndex<int, 11>> b; // this also works, not what I want
    Array<int, 10, checkIndex> c; // this doesn't work, but what I want
    return 0;
}
```

The last Array declaration in the `main` function is what I would like, where the template parameters of checkIndex match the previous template parameters in Array. However this doesn't compile (using Microsoft compiler). I get the following error:

```
error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(uint)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(uint)'
note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

Is there any way to get the desired result where the template parameters for the provided function get inferred from the other parameters?

Comment: Are the templates on `checkIndex` necessary in your actual code?

Comment: Also, you cannot pass a templated function pointer anywhere... it just doesn't exist. At the point where you want to pass a templated function you must instantiate it. This is why Vittorio turned your function into a struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May not be applicable in your real use case, but I suggest a *callable object* containing a function that does the check:

```
template<typename T, int size, typename fnIndex>
struct Array {
    T data[size];
    T& operator[](int index) {
        fnIndex{}.template check<size>(index);
        return data[index];
    }
};

struct checkIndex {
    template<int size>
    void check(int index) {
        assert(index < size);
    }    
};

int main() {    
    Array<int, 10, checkIndex> c;
    return 0;
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LD2hF7Lp4BUHR23V)

---

Let's analyze `fnIndex{}.template check<size>(index)`:

```
fnIndex{} // make a temporary object of type `fnIndex`
    .template check<size>(index) // call its `check` method using `size` 
                                 // as a template argument and `index` as
                                 // as a function argument
```

The `.template` disambiguation syntax is required because the compiler does not know what `check` means - it could be a field and the line could be interpreted as:

`fnIndex{}.check < size > (index)`

where `<` is the *less-than operator*, `>` is the *greater-than operator*, and `(index)` is an expression.

Using `.template` tells the compiler that we want to invoke a template method.

Comment: I tried your wandbox example, but it doesn't compile [wandbox example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/X3k1Up5CKsejqI7q)

Comment: @toteload: whoops, [fixed](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LD2hF7Lp4BUHR23V). I have a weird caching issue on wandbox on this machine...

Comment: @toteload: you're welcome. I added an explanation on the weird `.template` syntax.